# Remove annotations on stacked barplot where value is zero

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have created a stacked barplot showing % of occurrences between 2 classes of objects over a period of time. I have done a visualisation to show this, but I would like to remove annotations where the value of class 1 is = 0.

Here is the visualisation I have at the moment

[image: Visualisation]

If you notice on the picture above, on 29 and 31 (x-axis values) 0.00 appears where the xticks are supposed to be. I would like to remove these annotations in particular.

This is the code I wrote to create the visualisation:

```py
dat_grouped = dat.groupby(['Hours','Class'])['Amount'].sum()
ax_three = dat_grouped.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:round(100*x/x.sum(),3)).unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
for i in ax_three.patches:
    width,height=i.get_width(),i.get_height()
    x,y = i.get_xy()
    horiz_offset=1
    vert_offset=2
    ax_three.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(horiz_offset,vert_offset))
    ax_three.annotate('{:.2f} %'.format(height),(i.get_x()+.15*width,i.get_y()+.5*height),rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a condition to the annotation step:

```
if height > 0:
    ax_three.annotate('{:.2f} %'.format(height),
                      (i.get_x()+.15*width,
                       i.get_y()+.5*height),
                      rotation=90)
```

Side note: have you tried a line plot instead of a bar plot? Showing changes over time using a line makes more sense to me and might look less busy, but there's no hard answer to that.